# Properties won't update on input change

Tags: forms, authentication, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-2.x

I'm trying to adapt a working form I found for polymer 1.0 in order to work on polymer 2.0 but these two way data bindings don't seem to work.

My template:

```
<paper-input>
    <label>Username</label>
        <iron-input bind-value={{formData.username}}><input id="username" type="text" value="{{formData::input}}"></iron-input>
</paper-input>

<paper-input>
    <label>Password</label>
    <iron-input bind-value={{formData.password}}><input id="password" type="password" value="{{formData::input}}"></iron-input>
</paper-input>

<div class="wrapper-btns">
    <paper-button raised class="primary" on-tap="postLogin">Log In</paper-button>
    <paper-button class="link" on-tap="postRegister">Sign Up</paper-button>
</div>
```

My actions:

```
class MyLogin extends Polymer.Element {
    static get is() { return 'my-login'; }
    static get properties() {
        return {
            storedUser: Object,
            error: String,
            formData: {
                type: Object,
                value: {},
            },

        }
    }
    _setReqBody() {
        console.log(this.formData) // <--- THIS LINE!
        this.$.registerLoginAjax.body = this.formData;
    }
    postLogin() {
        this.$.registerLoginAjax.url = 'http://localhost:3001/sessions/create';
        this._setReqBody();
        this.$.registerLoginAjax.generateRequest();
    }
}
```

The indicate line will always print undefined though. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the full code: https://github.com/lpfjustino/PolymerQuickstart/blob/master/web/src/my-login.html
And here's the code mine is based on:
https://auth0.com/blog/build-your-first-app-with-polymer-and-web-components/

Answer (score 0):

`paper-input` doesn't need any `label` nor `iron-input` inside it by default. That only goes for `paper-input-container`. So the following would be okay

```
<paper-input label="Username" value="{{formData.username}}"></paper-input>
```

However if you insist on using `paper-input-container` instead, then

```
<paper-input-container>
  <label slot="label">Username</label>
  <iron-input bind-value="{{formData.username}}" slot="input">
    <!-- You don't need to add two-way binding for your input element here
         since `iron-input` already handles that for you using its `bind-value`
         attribute. -->
    <input />
  </iron-input>
</paper-input-container>
```

Also, when you declare an `Object` property, you should initialize it using a function to insure that each element instance would have its own copy of the property.

```
static get properties() {
  return {
    ...
    formData: {
      type: Object,
      value: function() {
        return {}; // or return { username: '', password: '' }
      },
    },
  };
}
```